# Getting Wrong Product URL on Product Listing Page

Tags: magento2.2, product-urls, product-listing

If a product has assigned in multiple categories.on product listing page, product
URL remains the same for each category.

e.g- Suppose a product "A" has assigned in category "B","C" & D where B,C,D already have parent category "view-all-category".

then whenever I visited the product "A" from all of these categories(B,C,D) each 
time I'm getting a unique product URL.

**Example:-**

**When visiting "A" from category "B" =>**

This is right-> http://localhost/view-all-category/B/A.html

**When visiting "A" from category "C" =>**

**Currently getting->** http://localhost/view-all-category/B/A.html

**Expected URL:-**  http://localhost/view-all-category/C/A.html

**When visiting "A" from category "D" =>**

**Currently getting->** http://localhost/view-all-category/B/A.html

**Expected URL:-** http://localhost/view-all-category/D/A.html

Note:- I've migrated from Magento 1 to Magento 2 using Magento Data Migration Tool & also using a custom theme.

Waiting forward the response.

Comment: Did you reindex all once?

Comment: yes, i've reindex.

Comment: Any update please?

Answer (score -1):

Finally, I've resolved the issue. to see the solution please visit here:-

http://nimb.ws/kH4PgT